# PIG How do I return a rowcount from 1 alias to another alias

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
REGISTER 'udf.py' using jython as myfunc;
loadhtml = load './assignment/crawler' using PigStorage('\u0001') as (id1:chararray,url:chararray,domain:chararray,content:chararray,source:chararray,date:chararray);
loadhtml_content = FOREACH loadhtml generate content;
flatten = FOREACH loadhtml_content generate flatten(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;
group = GROUP flatten by word;
count = FOREACH group1 generate $0, COUNT($1);
log = FOREACH count GENERATE myfunc.nLog($0,$1,**<I need to return the row count of loadhtml_content here>**);
```

I am trying to return a row count of loadhtml_content into another alias. I cant think of another idea to do it.

log = FOREACH count GENERATE myfunc.nLog($0,$1,**(I need to return the row count of loadhtml_content here)** );

Comment: Before getting to the row count,where are you getting 'line' from?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the exact feature you are looking for: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1434.
It essentially allows us to use single-tupled relations as constants wherever needed. 
Something along the following lines should address your question:

```
loadhtml_content = FOREACH loadhtml generate content;
content_rows = FOREACH (GROUP loadhtml_content ALL) GENERATE 
                   COUNT(loadhtml_content);
log = FOREACH count GENERATE myfunc.nLog($0,$1,content_rows.$0);
```